# How do I get curl to work with Visual Studio 2013 using nmake

Tags: curl, visual-studio-2013, nmake

So far I downloaded the most recent source code from their official website http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Using the VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt I went to the directory ...\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC and ran the vcvarsall.bat which I then change the directory to the source code in which I ran this line into the cmd `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=12`

A lot of text output but no errors. Now I want to use this in one of my projects, how do I add it so I can use the library of curl?

This is the first time ever using nmake, so I do not quite understand what to do after this.